# How to Get Max Date from GROUP BY - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

This is probably really basic but SQL is not my strongest skill set.
I have a basic SQL query to get the max date of the last inspection completed for a location.
I also want to know what type of inspection it was.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT
        facility_id
        ,max(inspection_date) as last_inspection
        ,inspection_type
    FROM facility_inspections
    GROUP BY facility_id  ,inspection_type
```

which gives me results that can have max dates for each inspection type for each each facility_id
like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
facility id | inspection date | inspection type 
-------------------------------------------------
93              04/28/2020        FULL
93              05/16/2018        VISIT
94              04/28/2020        LIMITED
94              06/12/2014        FULL
-------------------------------------------------
```

I want to return results that look like the follow because those have the true MAX date but also shows me the type of inspection that was completed:

```
-------------------------------------------------
facility id | inspection date | inspection type 
-------------------------------------------------
93              04/28/2020        FULL
94              04/28/2020        LIMITED
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keep` in an aggregation query:

```
SELECT facility_id, max(inspection_date) as last_inspection,
       max(inspection_type) keep (dense_rank first order by inspection_date desc)
FROM facility_inspections
GROUP BY facility_id;
```